# Can connect and access SQL Server database using SSMS and VS, but login fails in report code

Tags: sql-server, devexpress, database-connection

SQL Server login error being thrown when attempting to export DevExpress report, even though the same connection string is working fine elsewhere in code and other applications.

Error is as follows:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'USERNAME REMOVED'.

All code is referring to a single connection string in the `web.config` file.

I can remotely login and access the desired database in SSMS and VS's Server Explorer using the same login details. I have double checked the details being used are the same.

When I try to set up the connection for the report through VS's connection editor wizard, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this issue was due to special characters in the user's password, it appears that some applications were handling these characters and successfully logging into SQL Server under that username, while others could not.

Updating the user's password resolved the issue.